# JavaFX: Remove focused border in anchor pane

Tags: javafx, focus, border

I want to remove the red border when I focused my anchor pane. I have tried different things such as:

```
#rootPane {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

or programmtically
    rootPane.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent;");

I have a login screen with following fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="350" stylesheets="@Login_neu.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.erp.ui.login.LoginController_new">
    <children>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="ap_title" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="148.0" prefWidth="350.0">
                    <children>
                        <Text id="welcome-text" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="56.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Warehouse MMM Solution" wrappingWidth="270.13671875" />
                        <Text id="welcome-text2" layoutX="181.0" layoutY="76.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Powered by SAP" wrappingWidth="166.13671875" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="ap_login" layoutX="-4.0" layoutY="150.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="350.0">
                    <children>
                        <ProgressBar fx:id="progressbar" disable="true" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="312.0" maxHeight="3.0" minHeight="3.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                        <Button fx:id="btn_submit" layoutX="249.0" layoutY="268.0" onAction="#handleSubmitAction" text="Sign In" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="46.0">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets right="20.0" />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </Button>
                        <Label fx:id="lbl_username" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="38.0" text="Username:" />
                        <Label fx:id="lbl_plant" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="178.0" text="Plant:" />
                        <Label fx:id="lbl_password" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="106.0" text="Password" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tf_username" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="61.0" />
                        <PasswordField fx:id="pf_password" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="133.0" text="182832" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="cb_plants" disable="true" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="205.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

If I do this trick

```
#ap_login {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

or

```
 #rootPane {
        -fx-focus-color: transparent;
        -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
 }
```

only the button does take effect.

Css file looks like follow:

```
.root {
}

#welcome-text {
    -fx-font-size: 20.0px;
    -fx-fill: black;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#welcome-text2 {
    -fx-font-size: 14.0px;
    -fx-fill: black;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#ap_title {
    -fx-background-color: #9dd34c;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

#ap_login {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: An `AnchorPane` has no focus border by default (and the focus border is also not red by deafult). Please post your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My Css looks like follow:

`.root {
}

#welcome-text {
    -fx-font-size: 20.0px;
    -fx-fill: black;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#welcome-text2 {
 -fx-font-size: 14.0px;
 -fx-fill: black;
 -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#ap_title {
    -fx-background-color: #9dd34c;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

#ap_login {
 -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}`

Comment: @Texas Please [edit] your question with the additional material. That is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: There is no red border when running the code you have posted. Please [edit] the question so that it includes a [MCVE] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I solved the problem. The red border occured when I focussed the window, because when I changed my background I hooked in seetings unnoticley "Automatically pick an accent colour from my background".
I didn't think anything of it. So, next time I'll know it for sure. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The red border occured when I focussed the window, because when I changed my background I hooked in seetings unnoticley "Automatically pick an accent colour from my background". I didn't think anything of it. So, next time I'll know it for sure. Thanks anyway.